# use function call in dynamic SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, function, dynamic

inside a stored procedure i have a concatenated SQL Statement. this includes a large case Expression in select part. actually everything works fine when execute immediate command runs. now i want to make that statement better readable by pack this large case Expression in a function, but whatever i try it Fails. is it even possible to call functions inside dynamic SQLs?

Comment: Tag the dbms used.

Comment: yes it is but without code or errors cant really help

Comment: Use `dbms_output.put_line` to check your dynamic sql and run it in a separate block to see what errors you get and how you can fix them.

Comment: Remember to `grant execute` on the function. If it fails with a particular error, please post the error.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you're trying to execute, and an explanation of what "it Fails" means. Dynamically-executed SQL can call functions, so you need to provide a more detailed explanation of what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using 12c and you are only using this function for this sql statement you could use  a PL/SQL declaration section in the WITH clause of your sql statement

```
Declare
myvariable number;
Begin

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'
    WITH
      FUNCTION with_function(p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
      BEGIN
        RETURN p_id * p_id - p_id;
      END;
    SELECT with_function(3)
    FROM   dual
    WHERE  rownum = 1' into myvariable;
    dbms_output.put_line('myvariable: '||myvariable);
    End;
```